# Map becomes empty after sending it through express params

Tags: node.js, express, discord.js

I am using express and Discord.js.

website.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
//...
ap.get("/testpage/:guildID", checkAuth, (req, res) => {
  const guild = client.guilds.get(req.params.guildID); //get the guild object which holds further object maps
  //console.log(guild) output is expected with this console log
  //I made the guildRoles since I thought maybe I had to send the roles map instead of the guild object, but it does not work either
  const guildRoles = guild.roles;
  //console.log(guildRoles) has expected output
  renderTemplate(res, req, "configure.ejs", {guild, guildRoles});
};
```

configure.ejs

```
//...
<script>
  //...
  function testFunction() {
    let guildRolesVar = <%- guildRoles %>;
    console.log(guildRolesVar);
    //this outputs an empty object, {}, when it should return {...} ... with data in it
    //same with <%- guild %>, however, it does return data, however, object maps are empty (same as above), but things that are not maps 
  };
</script>
```

I expected that the object map data would pass over, but it doesn't, and I have no idea why.
A `guild` structure is:

```
Guild {
  roles:
    Collection [Map] {
      '1111111111111110' => Role {
        guild: [Circular],
        id: '1111111111111110',
        name: '@testRole' },
      '1837219387129378' => Role {
        guild: [Circular],
        id: '1837219387129378',
        name: '@anotherRole' } },
  name: 'the guild name',
  id: '12103981203980',
}
```

As you can see, the guild object has further object maps. When I console.log the guild object in my `app.get(...)`, it outputs the full data with nothing missing. However, when I pass the object through, the roles object is empty ({}).

Why is this happening and how can I get the full data?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely happening because express will JSON stringify() them and because discord.js objects have circular references the will be `{}`.
A possible solution would be to use d.js master/v12, such allows JSON.stringify() on its objects.